# How can I use Perl to grab text from a web page that is dynamically generated with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, perl, screen-scraping

There is a website I am trying to pull information from in Perl, however the section of the page I need is being generated using javascript so all you see in the source is:

```
<div id="results"></div>
```

I need to somehow pull out the contents of that div and save it to a file using Perl/proxies/whatever. e.g. the information I want to save would be

```
document.getElementById('results').innerHTML;
```

I am not sure if this is possible or if anyone had any ideas or a way to do this.
I was using a lynx source dump for other pages but since I cant straight forward screen scrape this page I came here to ask about it!

If anyone is interested, the page is http://downloadcenter.trendmicro.com/index.php?clk=left_nav&clkval=pattern_file&regs=NABU and the info I am trying to get is the row about the ConsumerOPR

Comment: I am also interested in this ... can you see and/or do you have access to the AJAX request URL (assuming the data is being populated through AJAX)?

Comment: Yes I can see the ajax, however on this site all that gets sent back from the ajax query is another js function which the results.innerHTML gets set to.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You'll need to reverse-engineer what the Javascript is doing. Does it fire off an AJAX request to populate the `<div>`? If so, it should be pretty easy to sniff the request using [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) and then duplicate it with [LWP::UserAgent](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/libwww-perl-5.834/lib/LWP/UserAgent.pm) or [WWW::Mechanize](http://search.cpan.org/~petdance/WWW-Mechanize/lib/WWW/Mechanize.pm) to get the information.

If the Javascript is just doing pure DOM manipulation, then that means the data must exist somewhere else in the page or the Javascript already. So figure out where it's coming from and grab it.

Finally, if none of those options are adequate, you may need to just use a real browser to do it. There are a few options for automating browser behavior, like [WWW::Mechanize::Firefox](http://search.cpan.org/~corion/WWW-Mechanize-Firefox/lib/WWW/Mechanize/Firefox.pm) or [Win32::IE::Mechanize](http://search.cpan.org/~abeltje/Win32-IE-Mechanize/lib/Win32/IE/Mechanize.pm).

Answer (score 7):

[Bringing the Browser to the Server](http://ejohn.org/blog/bringing-the-browser-to-the-server/) by [John Resig](http://ejohn.org/) might be useful.

Comment: Very interesting link. For many years, I had to this stuff the hard way. I am actually a little disappointed that it will be orders of magnitude easier now.

Comment: lol... as sites increase dynamic components, I welcome the ease of use ... I remember having to setup a dedicated server in order to run a browser for similar purposes.

Comment: Single dedicated server? How about four dedicated quad-CPU systems running 64 instances of IE simultaneously? ;-)

Answer (score 4):

As the content of your page is generated by some Javascript, you need the ability to :

- Execute some Javascript code

  - Even, possibly, some complex JS code, doing Ajax requests and all that ?
- And do it with an engine that supports the functions/methods that are present in a browser *(like DOM manipulations)*

A solution could be to actually really start a browser to navigate to that page, and, then, parse the page that's loaded by it, to extract the information ?

I've never used this for grabbing, but the [Selenium suite](http://seleniumhq.org/) might help, here : using Selenium RC, you can start a real browser, and pilot it -- then, you have functions to get data from it.

It's not quite fast, and it's pretty heavy *(it has to start a browser !)*, but it works quite well : you'll be using Firefox, for example, to navigate to your page -- which means a real Javascript engine, that's used every day by a lot of people ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This might be what your looking for (in PHP):

```
$url = 'http://downloadcenter.trendmicro.com/ajx/pattern_result.php';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'q=patresult_page&reg=NABU');
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$content = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo $content;
exit;
```

once you get the content you can use something like: http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/ to parse the results you need or a similar perl equivalent???

And/or do the parsing yourself.

FYI: all I did was use firebug to inspect the requests and recreated it with PHP/CURL...

Answer (score 0):

to work with the dynamically created HTML you can use the FireFox [Chickenfoot](http://groups.csail.mit.edu/uid/chickenfoot/) plugin.
Or if you need something that works from a command line script use bindings to Perl. I have done this with Python before.